# How can i "compile" ESModule from a string?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have a string variable with some code which is essentially ESModule:

```
let name = "test_snippet";
let injectedCode =
`const callback = (environment, ..._) => {
  function ${name}() {
    const global = (0,eval)("this");
    global.works = true;
    console.info("${name} works!");
  }
  const injectedSnippetsList = ["${name}"];
  const injectedSnippetsCallbacks = [${name}];
  const snippets = {};
  for (let e = 0, { length: t} = injectedSnippetsList; e < t; e++)
    snippets[injectedSnippetsList[e]] = injectedSnippetsCallbacks[e];
  for (let [name, ...args] of _) {
    if (snippets.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      try {
        snippets[name](...args);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  }
};
callback.has = snippet => [
  "${name}"
].includes(snippet);
export default callback;
`;
```

How can i "compile" it into ESModule to call it's `has` for example?
I have the following:

```
async function compileModule(code)
{
  let moduleData = "data:text/javascript;base64," + btoa(code);
  return await import(moduleData);
}
```

but it interprets `moduleData` as module path, not as a "content", resulting in "failed to load".
Any suggestions?